# Demonstrate intranet laptop site on iPad

Tags: ipad

We have an application which is intended for intranet use. It's not available on the web and we'd prefer to keep it that way.

In house the iPad can connect to the wifi and we can demonstrate the website that way. At a customers is there any way of connecting the iPad to the laptop and showing a website running on IIS off that laptop?

The only way I can think of is by attaching a router to the laptop and running a local network that way, not sure if customers would be entirely comfortable with that

We could also look into some kind of VPN arrangement? It would be so much easier if we could connect the iPad and laptop though

thanks

(Edit) Is Bluetooth a possibility?

Answer (score 0):

I did a huge kludge when I needed something like that. I don't really recommend it because it's annoying, but it works to some level.

1. Connect your phone to the laptop, sharing the 3G connection via USB.
2. On the laptop, share that USB connection via WiFi.
3. Connect the iPad to the laptop's access point (WiFi)
4. The iPad should now be able to "see" the webserver that runs on your laptop